# Autowired repositories are null everywhere except main()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, autowired, alexa-skills-kit

I'm able to get the repository functionality working from inside main() but nowhere else.

From everything I've read, this seems to have something to do with @Autowired members I'm trying to use being created outside of Spring's "context" or "container.

The typical culprit other people seem to come up with has to do with using "new" to create an object that ends up outside of Spring's scope but I've done everything I can to make sure everything that relies on something being @Autowired is created by Spring itself.

I have the following simple oneOff() method inside my main() method for printing out the first 10 names which, when run, works as expected:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Autowired
    private AppointmentServlet appointmentServlet;

    @Autowired
    private IAppointmentRepository appointmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private IStaffMemberRepository staffMemberRepository;

    @Autowired
    private IStaffMemberRepository clientRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        Application app = context.getBean(Application.class);
        app.oneOff();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(appointmentServlet,     "/AppointmentManager/NextAppointment");
    }

    private void oneOff() {
        System.out.println("\n=================== Starting lookup ===================");
        try {

        int limit = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            StaffMember member = staffMemberRepository.findAll().get(i);
            String firstName = member.getFirstName();
            String lastName = member.getLastName();
            if (firstName == null || firstName.equals("UNKNOWN") || firstName.isEmpty()) {
                limit++;
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Staff member: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        System.out.println("NPE: Lookup failed");
    } System.out.println("==================== Ending lookup ===================");
}
```

}

Which produces:

```
=================== Starting lookup ===================
Staff member: JOSE  BEJARANO
Staff member: KARIMAH ABDUL-AZIZ
Staff member: CONNIE ABED
Staff member: WALID ABI-SAAB
Staff member: BARRY ABRAHAM
Staff member: JENNA ACEYCEK
Staff member: DANIEL ADAMCZ YK
Staff member: TYMOTEUSZ ADAMCZYK
Staff member: ELIZABETH ADAMS
Staff member: ERIN ADAMS
==================== Ending lookup ===================
```

However, when I call a duplicate method that's just pasted into my servlet class, the repositories never get instantiated and I get NullPointerExceptions.

Servlet Class:

```
@Component
public class AppointmentServlet extends SpeechletServlet {

    @Autowired
    private AppointmentSpeechlet appointmentSpeechlet;

    public AppointmentServlet() {
        this.setSpeechlet(appointmentSpeechlet);
    }

}
```

Speechlet class where repositories are actually being used:

```
@Component
public class AppointmentSpeechlet implements Speechlet {

    @Autowired
    private IAppointmentRepository appointmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private IStaffMemberRepository staffMemberRepository;

    @Autowired
    private IClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Override
    public SpeechletResponse onIntent(final IntentRequest request, final Session session) throws SpeechletException {
        oneOff();
    }
}
```

oneOff() method again:

```
private void oneOff() {
    System.out.println("\n=================== Starting lookup ===================");
    try {

    int limit = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        StaffMember member = staffMemberRepository.findAll().get(i);
        String firstName = member.getFirstName();
        String lastName = member.getLastName();
        if (firstName == null || firstName.equals("UNKNOWN") || firstName.isEmpty()) {
            limit++;
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println("Staff member: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
    }
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        System.out.println("NPE: Lookup failed");
    } System.out.println("==================== Ending lookup ===================");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added `@Component` to your servlet class, but that does not make it a Spring-managed bean. In fact, the servlet container (Tomcat, for example) instantiates and manages the instance of your servlet class, and it knows nothing about Spring - so your servlet is not created as a Spring bean and hence, autowiring does not work.

The best solution would be to use [Spring Web MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc) and write a `@Controller` class instead of writing your own servlet. If you can't do that, you can use [`WebApplicationContextUtils`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html) to lookup the Spring application context from within your servlet, in which you can lookup the Spring beans (instead of autowiring them in your servlet).

Comment: Thank you so much for this! What you said makes perfect sense and would have taken me an eternity to figure out on my own. I'm going to try out your suggestions and I'll be sure to come back with my results.

Comment: @MikeMedina If your goal is to make a REST webservice with Spring Boot, then that's super-easy with Spring Data JPA and Spring Data REST; see for example this guide: [Accessing JPA Data with REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)

Comment: I'm developing the web-service backend for an Amazon Alexa skill which requires that I use their "SpeechletServlet" implementation

Comment: I can implement ApplicationContextAware to get access to Spring's ApplicationContext but how do I get an instance of my repository interfaces from there?

Comment: @MikeMedina Look them up in the app context, for example: `IAppointmentRepository appointmentRepository = context.getBean(IAppointmentRepository.class);`